# Error: can not fine method findViewByID in onPageFinished of WebViewClient Class

Tags: imageview, findviewbyid, splash-js-render

I asked following question 1 month back , people here are not interested in replying  questions , but they can spend hours and trolling who ask the questions, to increase their so called reputation,  perhaps it can be called as bad reputation.  so now I only answer this question, but these (bad) reputed trollers may not approve the post. 
-----------------------the question was---------------------- 
In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/a/9589451) example `findViewById` is called in `onPageFinished` of webview class, but when I am trying to do the same, it is giving error:

> Error: can not find method `findViewByID`

Source Code:

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
  ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


logo.setVisibility(0);
}
```

---

the answer is as follows
declare
public ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
in main activity.

then in onPageFinished set visibility to invisible of imageview as follows
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    logo.setVisibility(0);
    }